# TypeError: $(...).jqGrid is not a function on button click to trigger reload

Tags: jqgrid

My grid loads fine for the first time. But on button click , I need to reload the grid and it gives the error 'TypeError: $(...).jqGrid is not a function'.

This happens both in firefox and chrome.
Please help.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/themes/jquery-ui-1-10-TW-custom/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
<LINK rel=STYLESHEET href="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/themes/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css"    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></LINK>

<script type='text/javascript' src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/js/plugins/jqModal.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="<%= request.getContextPath()%>/js/plugins/jquery.tablednd.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#gridData").jqGrid({
    url:contextPath + "/psapi/esppPreclearance.do?method=gridData&stockClass="+ $("[name=stockClass]").val()+"&transactionType="+$("[name=transactionType]").val(),
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['<bean:message key="plansetup.label.stockclass" />','<bean:message    key="windowPeriod.label.dispTypeCode" />',
           '<bean:message key="windowPeriod.label.fromDate" />', '<bean:message key="windowPeriod.label.toDate" />', '<bean:message key="windowPeriod.label.ParticipantLevel" />',
        '<bean:message  key="participantBenificiary.label.seqNo" />',
           '<bean:message   key="windowPeriod.label.product" />', '<bean:message    key="windowPeriod.label.participantGrp" />', 
           '<bean:message   key="participantGroup.label.Participant-id" />','<bean:message  key="common.label.activeStatus" />'],
         autowidth: true,
    pager: '#pager',
    colModel:[
        {name:'stockClass',index:'stockClass', width:60},
        {name:'transTypeDesc',index:'transTypeDesc', width:90},
        {name:'frmDate',index:'fromDate', width:100, sorttype:"date"},
        {name:'toDate',index:'toDate', width:100, sorttype:"date"},
        {name:'prdLvlDesc',index:'prdLvlDesc', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"},
        {name:'prdSeqNo',index:'prdSeqNo', width:30, align:"right"},        
        {name:'productId',index:'productId', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"int"},       
        {name:'partGroup',index:'partGroup', width:30, align:"right",},
        {name:'globalId',index:'globalId', width:80, align:"right",},
        {name:'activeFlg',index:'activeFlg', width:50, align:"center    "},
    ],
    loadonce: true,
    multiselect: false,
    rowNum:20,
    viewrecods: true,
    rowlist:[10,20,30,40,50],
    height:463,


});




jQuery("#gridData").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});


$("[name=btnFind]").click(function()
        {
            $("#gridData").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json"}).trigger("reloadGrid");
            alert("I AM OUT");

        });




});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that either jqGrid or some dependent JavaScript file was not loaded or unsuccessfully loaded (loaded in the wrong order for example).

You need verify which JavaScript files are really loaded and to fix the order of loaded files. For example you need move `grid.locale-en.js` **after** `jquery-1.11.1.js`, I recommend you to remove loading of `jquery.jqGrid.js`, `jqModal.js` and `jquery.tablednd.js` and to load `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead. One should first load jQuery, then `grid.locale-en.js` and then `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. By the way you can get jqGrid files from CDN cdnjs.com (see [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jqgrid)).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried  that but it does not work. Actually, even if I put the entire initial loading of the grid , inside the button 'click' function, it does not work.

Comment: @gmk: You are welcome! What error you have now? Is the error 'TypeError: $(...).jqGrid is not a function', which you asked in your question, fixed now? I suppose you need *debug* your code. You should start Developer Tools (press F12 to start) and start JavaScript debugging.

Comment: I can cause the same error by calling reloadGrid and then trying to refer to any jqGrid function. So missing JavaScript files might be the issue, but it's not the only possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

@Olga, thank you again for taking the time to respond. I took to your word and debugged and saw multiple versions of jquery files were present in my workspace. I removed them all and kept, only 1 version and the code started working file. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

@GMK It may be occurred by below reasons

**1. if you are using more than one jquery file i.e. Layout/template has one and other one in view/HTML file**

**2. If you have diffrent version files**