# jqGrid is not a function

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to use jqgrid 5.1.1 and I got this error: $('#gridMain').jqgrid is not a function.

I don't know what to do solve the problem.

Please help me!!

Here is my code

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR" pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-kr" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<title>My First Grid</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/jqgrid_5.1.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="/jqgrid_5.1.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/jqgrid_5.1.0/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/jqGrid_5.1.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-kr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function (){
      console.log("aa");
   $('#gridMain').jqGrid({});
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <h2>jqGrid test</h2>
    <table id="gridMain"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj2IJ.jpg)

Comment: This usually happen when the required js libraries are not loaded properly. Based on your code, my suspicion is that the following paths could be wrong - 

"/jqgrid_5.1.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" 
"/jqgrid_5.1.0/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"

Also, why are you referencing 2 versions of the jquery library?

Comment: Potential duplicate of this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370345/typeerror-jqgrid-is-not-a-function-on-button-click-to-trigger-reload

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The cause was a wrong path.

Thank you for your commnet!!!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid_5.1.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid_5.1.0/css/custom.jqgrid.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jqgrid_5.1.0/css/ui.jqgrid-bootstrap.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script src="jqgrid_5.1.0/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="jqgrid_5.1.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-kr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```